# ¿Como puedo instalar Apache Maven en Ubuntu 15.10 usando apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, maven

¿Existe alguna forma de instalar **Apache Maven** con `apt-get`?

Por ahora tengo que ir al sitio de Apache Maven y descargo los archivos y luego desde mi editor (Eclipse, IntelliJ) hago referencia a ese folder para dejarlo configurado.

Me gustaría saber si existe una forma de configurarlo usando `apt-get` para no tener que hacer todo lo mencionado.

Comment: yo creo que te entiendo, pero igual es cosa mia, ¿no crees que eso de instalacion manual confunde un poco, cuando despues dices apt? por otro lado quizas esto te ayude si entendi tu pregunta -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630055/how-to-install-maven-3-on-ubuntu-15-10-15-04-14-10-14-04-lts-13-10-13-04-12-10-1 Saludos

Comment: has usado sudo apt-get install maven

Comment: Que yo sepa no lo instalas asi. Solo descargas la distribucion (un tar) y lo colocas en la ruta que gustes.

Comment: He encontrado [este tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-ubuntu/). ¿Lo viste antes? ¿Has intentado seguirlo?

Comment: Por alguna razon no encontraba el paquete usando solo sudo apt-get install maven, reinstale ubuntu y ya funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe funcionar usando el siguiente comando:

```
 sudo apt-get install maven
```

Comment: Por alguna razon no funcionaba, reinstale ubuntu y funciono sin problemas, gracias!